# Creating a table with one of the column values from an expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to create a table that I can use for Accounts Receivable. It's a very simple  table, needing only the total cost of an order, how much has been paid into the order, and the order number itself. I'm trying to adapt an existing query used for report generation to do so.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
      Round(Sum(nz([Quantity]*[UnitPrice]*(1-[Discount])*100)/100)+
            [RushCharge],2) AS TotalCost, 
      [Sum Of Payments Query].[Total Payments], 
      [Order Details].RushCharge AS RushCharge,
      Orders.OrderID,
      Orders.Cancel,
      Orders.PriceQuote 
INTO test2
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN [Sum Of Payments Query] 
             ON Orders.OrderID = [Sum Of Payments Query].OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.OrderID,
         Orders.Cancel,
         [Sum Of Payments Query].[Total Payments],
         Orders.PriceQuote
```

The issue is the age of the DB, where the total cost of an order is always dynamically generated instead of being stored somewhere (Even though there is only one form that alters it, but still), meaning I have to resort to the same. The Round function calculates the total cost of the order, and it works elsewhere, but here, it just prompts me for values instead of pulling them from Orders.

What am I doing wrong? I know it has to be something simple.

Comment: shouldn't unit price be fixed at the time of purchase? start your trouble shooting by commenting out "Into Test2"

Comment: What is "nz([Quantity]"?

Comment: why are you using group by on [Sum Of Payments Query].[Total Payments] ?

Comment: @Goat_CO has it the nail on the head.  The problem is liekly "nz"

Comment: @jsobo I just looked it up, it's a function in Access, roughly equivalent to ISNULL().
And Justin, kindly tag the question with the appropriate DBMS, assuming Access in this case, and which version can be helpful too.

Comment: The Unit Price, Discount, Quantity, and RushCharge are all generated in another form and stored in the table. TotalCost is essentially what the customer would pay, which is not stored anywhere in the database, but dynamically generated each time. And removing the "Into Test2" generates the same issue, it's not pulling the values from the tables, just prompting me for them.

Group by on is required to stop the "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified" error that generates otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that [Quantity], [unit price] and [Discount] and RushCharge are fields in [order details] table, which is not included in the query.

you could create a query that returns the totalcost per order

```
select orderid,
       Round(Sum(nz([Quantity]*[UnitPrice]*(1-[Discount])*100)/100)+
            [RushCharge],2) AS TotalCost from 
from [order details]
group by orderid
```

and include this in your query in the same way you have [sum of Payments Query]

Comment: I had to tweak the SQL a bit, but this basically pulled what I wanted into a right proper table. From there, I was able to use joins to get where I wanted. Thanks!